# JavaScript ES6 Loading file mechanism

Tags: javascript, json, express, webpack, ecmascript-6

i'm working on a JavaScript and React application that uses WebPack and a Express server. And i actually have a question about the loading file mechanism.

I wasn't able to find the answer yet. So here i go.

Let's say that i have an `app.js` file that does something like `import whatever from someJSONfile` where i'm importing some content from a JSON file on the frontend.

And here's my question, that content `whatever` gets loaded into memory **every** time that i execute that `app.js` file? Or it just gets loaded the first time and the following executions `webpack`, or whatever the responsible is, is going to search for the content of that file without loading it again?

I'm just concerned that every time that `app.js` gets executed the files inside, like the JSON of the example, will get loaded again every time.

Thanks and i hope i was clear enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack is smart enough to cache the loaded modules (in fact, inside the bundler, it will load one time, despite of how many times you import it).

Look at this example:

**file1.js**

```
import json from './data.json'
export default json
```

**file2.js**

```
import json from './data.json'
export default json
```

**main.js**

```
import json1 from './file1.js'
import json2 from './file2.js'

console.log(json1 === json2); //true (same reference)
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! That's what i wanted to know

Comment: FWIW, the ECMAScript specification also requires a module file to only be evaluated once.